# 2 Implement: Remove your own content

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, chat

This site has serious issues, core issues. Some of them could be solved. I wonder if the community is developed enough to correctly deal with them.

The second issue is that we should have a rule like:

> No Regrets ™

*Everyone should be the owner of what they said, everyone should be able to regret what was said and remove it, no limits.*

That means that:

- Everyone should be able to remove their comments at any time (as it is now).
- Everyone should be able to remove chat posts (what comments become when pushed aside) at any time. Presently it is only allowed after asking a moderator and when he agrees to do it (most of the time they don't).
- Everyone should be able to erase questions and answers. If the content of questions and answers can not be directly erased, make the question/answer an orphan. Any one could later "adopt" the orphaned question/answer and modify it as needed. No-one will be stuck with UN-wanted content.

Comment: When you say *Everyone should be able to erase questions and answers*, I suppose you mean *Everyone should be able to erase **their own** questions and answers*?

Comment: Note that deleting a question would also mean deleting the answers to that question (generally by other users). If you delete a chat message, then the chat conversion starts to make a lot less senses.

Comment: (1) Yes (their own content). (2) To avoid actually removing a question I am proposing that the question could become *an orphan* (no owner), much as it is now done with `user****`. But the name of the owner gets erased by the request of the same question owner. After a question has become "an orphan", anyone could ask to adopt it (the exact method to select or assign a new owner could be discussed) and then clean it, improve it, etc.

Comment: (3) Chat(1): What I am initially asking is for comments that **have been converted** to chat messages via the *comments are not meant for long discussions* action that removes all comments and makes them a chat. Those **were** comments, but got transformed by someone else than the original comment owner.

Comment: (4)Chat(2): But yes, in general a **No Regrets ™** rules must allow anyone to remove their own content even in chats.

Answer (score 3):

> Everyone should be able to remove chat posts (what comments become when pushed aside) at any time. Presently it is only allowed after asking a moderator and when he agrees to do it (most of the time they don't).

As for this, I do agree in that it should be possible to remove chat posts that used to be comments, in exactly the same way as it was possible to remove them when they still were comments. The fact that comments can get turned into something non-removable contradicts badly with how they're vocally advertised as volatile and "removable at any time".

But that's hardly specific to unix.SE, and probably can't be achieved here, if at all.

(I have no comment on chat messages originally posted as chat messages.)

Comment: Yep, this is a network-wide thing, it can't be changed for a specific site. I think the idea was to stop people from saying something unpleasant and then pretending they didn't.

Comment: @terdon, which they can still do in comments if they're removed before they get moved to chat. Whatever the reason, the logic doesn't work.

Comment: The logic (which I am not defending, only explaining as I have guessed it) is for chat. I don't think they considered the case where something was moved from a comment to a chat room so the rules for chat were applied.

Comment: @terdon, yes, exactly. "I don't think they considered" explains too many things in this world.